# Mixed authorization (Windows NTLM & anonymous) in selfhosted owin application not working - "Authorization has been denied for this request"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, ntlm-authentication, self-host-webapi

I am trying to develop selfhosted OWIN WebApp. Everything OK, until I tried to integrate Windows (NTLM) authentication. Windows authentication works fine if only IntegratedWindowsAuthentication is activated. But I need some of the requests to remain anonymous.

I already found that I have to enable both authentication methods:

```
AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication | AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous
```

But in such case I get "Authorization has been denied for this request". Tested with Chrome as client (http://localhost:9009/api/test).

Please help.

OWIN startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        // Enable Windows & Anonymous Authentification
        HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
        listener.AuthenticationSchemes = 
                AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication | AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
        );
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Main program:

```
static void Main()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9009/";

        // Start OWIN host 
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server ready");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Test controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace SelfhostNTAuth

{
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        WindowsPrincipal user = RequestContext.Principal as WindowsPrincipal;

        if (user == null)
        {
            return new string[] { "unauthorized"};
        }
        else
        {
            return new string[] { user.Identity.AuthenticationType, user.Identity.Name };
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to use the [AuthenticationSchemeSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.authenticationschemeselector?view=netframework-4.8) to return the authentication scheme based on some criteria.

```
// Specify the authentication delegate.
listener.AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate = 
    new AuthenticationSchemeSelector (AuthenticationSchemeForClient);
```

```
static AuthenticationSchemes AuthenticationSchemeForClient(HttpListenerRequest request)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Client authentication protocol selection in progress...");
    // Do not authenticate local machine requests.
    if (request.RemoteEndPoint.Address.Equals (IPAddress.Loopback))
    {
        return AuthenticationSchemes.None;
    }
    else
    {
        return AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
    }
}
```